# Prove that a definition of $\mathcal{I}$ does not satisfy the exchange property

Tags: co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

For a graph $G=(V,E)$ ($V$ set of vertices and $E$ set of edges ), $\mathcal{I}$ is defined as  all of the subsets $E´\subseteq E$ where the components of $(V,E´)$ that are connected are simple paths. I want to show that $(E,\mathcal{I})$ does not satisfy the exchange property of a matroid.

I have tried to find an example by drawing two graphs, that is, two graphs with all of the vertices $V$ and where each graph has a set of edges and the edges that are connected are simple paths (no cycles). And I tried to make one graph have more edges than the other and find an example where we can NOT add an edge that is in the graph with more edges (but not in the graph with less edges) to the graph with less edges. I always find an edge that can be added.

But I can not find such an example and I am stuck. Maybe there is a simpler way to prove it?

Comment: it may help to use appropriate software (in the case at hand, try to define your matroid using `Matroid([E, I], check=True, regular=True)` in sage.  Either this works, then you have a conjecture, or it doesn't, then it will give you a counterexample.)

Comment: You won’t be able to find an example because you are trying to do the wrong thing. You say that you are trying find a pair forests that fail the exchange axiom, but forests *satisfy* the exchange axiom. The point of the exercise is that “unions of simple paths” don’t satisfy it....

Comment: @GordonRoyle thats true, I changed my post now. Have I still interpreted the assignment wrong you think?

Comment: Is this question a homework assignment?

Comment: @WillSawin Not exactly, The homework was to show that is is not a matroid. And I already figured out that it is hereditary but was stuck on the exchange part. But my problem was really that I did not understand completely what a simple path looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take two paths $1234,5678$. Assume that there are no edges between their endpoints (so that you can not enlarge this independent set of 6 edges) but there exists a Hamiltonian path, say 13657428. You get two inclusion-maximal subsets of different size, thus it is not a matroid.